# What to use in place of to_date in order to convert or cast

Tags: azure, azure-synapse

What to use in place of to_date in order to convert it into a correct format I have tried using cast but its giving me error. the encounter_attr.attr_value is originally storing the varchar(100) but its not getting formated to YYYY-MM-DD format. Below is the code:

```
INSERT INTO ccsm.trn_encounter_converted_attr (person_id, encounter_id, attr_name, attr_desc, attr_type, attr_value,
                                               date_value, dt_create)
  (SELECT
     encounter_attr.person_id                         AS person_id,
     encounter_attr.encounter_id                      AS encounter_id,
     encounter_attr.attr_name                         AS attr_name,
     encounter_attr.attr_desc                         AS attr_desc,
     encounter_attr.attr_type                         AS attr_type,
     encounter_attr.attr_value                        AS attr_value,
     to_date(encounter_attr.attr_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_value,
     cast(getdate() as date)                                     AS dt_create
   FROM ccsm.trn_encounter_attr encounter_attr
   WHERE encounter_attr.attr_type = 'timestamp');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can used a combination of FORMAT and CAST to achieve the functionality. Simplifying your query, it would be something like this:

```
SELECT
    FORMAT( encounter_attr.attr_value, 'yyyy-MM-dd' ) AS 'date_value'
```

Comment: `FORMAT` is not supported on Azure SQL Data Warehouse as far as I'm aware?

Comment: Thanks for the update @MattUsher, I was wondering if it was a gen2 thing or something.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `CONVERT` in Azure SQL Data Warehouse to convert strings to `DATE`, eg this worked for me with a `VARCHAR` value in the format `yyyy-MM-dd` or `yyyyMMdd`:

```
SELECT
    encounter_attr.person_id                         AS person_id,
    encounter_attr.encounter_id                      AS encounter_id,
    encounter_attr.attr_name                         AS attr_name,
    encounter_attr.attr_desc                         AS attr_desc,
    encounter_attr.attr_type                         AS attr_type,
    encounter_attr.attr_value                        AS attr_value,
    CONVERT( DATE, encounter_attr.attr_value )       AS date_value,
    --to_date(encounter_attr.attr_value, 'YYYY-MM-DD') AS date_value,
    cast(getdate() as date)                                     AS dt_create
FROM ccsm.trn_encounter_attr encounter_attr
WHERE encounter_attr.attr_type = 'timestamp';
```

`CAST` also worked for me so not sure why you are getting an error.  Can you post some sample data?